# Usage of InstallShield 2012 with database

Tags: c#, sql, installshield-2012

I have made an application in VS2012 that uses a database to store and retrieve data and I'd like to create a setup file for this application, currently I use InstallShield LE 2012.

I've tried to deploy the application with that, but when I install it in another computer it throws me an exception due to the database.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the exception being thrown?

Comment: "NullReferenceException: object not set to an instace of an object". And when I look for a contact in the deployed application in throws me something like the next: "Server not found", is something about the connection string with the database

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a Null reference exception error this is normally because some place in the code there is a failure to create an object. Then at a later point the use of this object fails with a Null Exception because the object does not exist.

In this case is sounds like there is a failure to create some object that is a dependency for creating the database. I know this does not really give much more insight into why this is happening.  But here are some points to look for.

- Is the target PC running an SQL server, or does your Install package deploy SQL Express?
- Is it a MS SQL DB or Other
- Does the user that you are running the install shield under have permissions on the SQL Server to create a database?